# Error android firebase java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm getting error on getUid()

```
final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

and this my activity code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView postList;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseUsers;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthListener;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            }
        };

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

        postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_list);
        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        postList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        CheckUserExist();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

                Blog.class,
                R.layout.post_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDescription());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

            }
        };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

    }
    private void CheckUserExist() {

        final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

        mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){
                    Intent SetupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                    SetupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(SetupIntent);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }

    public static class BlogViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        View mView;

        public BlogViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mView = itemView;
        }
        public void setTitle(String title){
            TextView post_title = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_title);
            post_title.setText(title);
        }

        public void setDesc(String desc){
            TextView post_desc = (TextView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_desc);
            post_desc.setText(desc);
        }

        public void setImage(final Context ctx, final String image){
            final ImageView post_image = (ImageView) mView.findViewById(R.id.post_img);
//            Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
                Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).networkPolicy(NetworkPolicy.OFFLINE).into(post_image, new Callback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess() {

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError() {
                        Picasso.with(ctx).load(image).into(post_image);
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main_menu, menu);

        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_add){
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostActivity.class));
        }

        if (item.getItemId() == R.id.action_logout){
            logout();
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    private void logout() {
        mAuth.signOut();
    }
}
```

Comment: CheckUserExist();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener); swap this line call CheckUserExist(); after mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

Comment: still get the same error @ZakiPathan

Comment: post your error @Ragils

Comment: [link](http://imgur.com/a/lZyNq) check this @ZakiPathan

Comment: @Ragils pic is not complete please post your error log

Comment: @Shashanth I just get an error on that activity , whether to post all activity / code ??

Comment: Only the error log and don't post screenshots it's hard to read

Comment: error log on logcat? @Shashanth ;@CodFather

Comment: Yes what you posted in screenshot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem happens when you try to call `mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid()`. Apparently there is no current user at the time, so that call fails.

Instead use:

```
private void CheckUserExist() {
  if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
    final String user_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabaseUsers.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if (!dataSnapshot.hasChild(user_id)){
                Intent SetupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                SetupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(SetupIntent);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
  }
}
```

In general, you'll want to use an auth state listener for this, similar to the one you already have in `onCreate`.

In fact, it seems to me that both could easily be folded into a single listener: one that starts the login activity if the user isn't signed in and optionally registers the user with the database if they are.

The code for that:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
    mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

    mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
    mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

    postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_list);
    postList.setHasFixedSize(true);

    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

    postList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    CheckUserExist();

    FirebaseAuth.getInstance().addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            FirebaseUser user = firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();
            if (user == null){
                // The user is not signed in, start login flow
                Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(loginIntent);
            }
            else {
                // The user is signed in, register them in database
                String user_id = user.getUid();

                mDatabaseUsers.child(user_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        if (!dataSnapshot.exists()){
                            Intent SetupIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SetupActivity.class);
                            SetupIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                            startActivity(SetupIntent);
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
                throw databaseError.toException(); // don't ignore onCancelled
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

    FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

            Blog.class,
            R.layout.post_row,
            BlogViewHolder.class,
            mDatabase

    ) {
        @Override
        protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

            viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
            viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDescription());
            viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

        }
    };
    postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);

}
```

I also fixed the way you check if the user already exists in the database. Retrieving all users to then client-side check if one of the keys exists is a waste of bandwidth that will become especially evident as your number of users grows. The code I wrote checks precisely whether this user's UID already exists in the database, which is the minimum data you can check.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are not initializing mauth.
remove onstart method and copy the code to oncreate. oncreate will be

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mAuthListener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
                if (firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() == null){
                    Intent loginIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
                    loginIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    startActivity(loginIntent);
                }
            }
        };

        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Blog");
        mDatabaseUsers = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users");

        mDatabase.keepSynced(true);
        mDatabaseUsers.keepSynced(true);

        postList = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.post_list);
        postList.setHasFixedSize(true);

        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
        layoutManager.setStackFromEnd(true);

        postList.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
CheckUserExist();

        mAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthListener);

        FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder> firebaseRecyclerAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter<Blog, BlogViewHolder>(

                Blog.class,
                R.layout.post_row,
                BlogViewHolder.class,
                mDatabase

        ) {
            @Override
            protected void populateViewHolder(BlogViewHolder viewHolder, Blog model, int position) {

                viewHolder.setTitle(model.getTitle());
                viewHolder.setDesc(model.getDescription());
                viewHolder.setImage(getApplicationContext(), model.getImage());

            }
        };
        postList.setAdapter(firebaseRecyclerAdapter);


    }
```